# How do you make this Else if?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to check a range for different values and then change a value in another column but every time I do it error stating:

> Else without If

```
For i = 1 To 3000
    With Sheets("Order Approvers")
      If .Range("C" & i).Value = "No Approval Required" Then _
        .Range("F" & i).Value = ""
      'Else <<< illegal here??
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: Show your [mcve]. We can't help you with syntax if you don't show what you wrote that is contrary to the syntax rules of the language.

Comment: @jdv edited, hope it helps.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I'm not sure that's a good edit to have made. There was no `Else` of any kind in the code provided by the OP. That's changing the meaning - the OP needs to confirm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used the line continue character `_` at the end of your if-statement. That glues the next statement directly to the `If`-statement. Basically, it means the same as writing

```
If .Range("C" & i).Value = "No Approval Required" Then .Range("F" & i).Value = ""
```

When you have the statement written like that, you cannot use an `Else` (technically, you can, but you have to put that also in the same line and that is something you don't want...)

You can use `ElseIf` if you have another condition to check, `Else` for all the other cases. At the end, you need to put `End If` 
So, just write

```
If .Range("C" & i).Value = "No Approval Required" Then 
    .Range("F" & i).Value = ""
ElseIf (...) Then
    .Range("F" & i).Value = "whatever"
Else
    .Range("F" & i).Value = "something else"
End If
```

Answer (score 5):

That underscore is misleading:

```
  If .Range("C" & i).Value = "No Approval Required" Then _
    .Range("F" & i).Value = ""
```

It *looks* like `If...Then...End If` block syntax, but it isn't. The `_` line continuation makes the *logical* line of code be actually like this:

```
  If .Range("C" & i).Value = "No Approval Required" Then .Range("F" & i).Value = ""
```

And that's completely legal.

You could continue the same logical line of code with an `Else` clause:

```
  If .Range("C" & i).Value = "No Approval Required" Then .Range("F" & i).Value = "" Else ...
```

And that would still be legal.

However what you can't do, is this:

```
  If .Range("C" & i).Value = "No Approval Required" Then .Range("F" & i).Value = ""
  Else ....
```

Because that `Else` belongs to another syntactic expression: the `If` statement above it is complete; the next statement starting with `Else` has to be illegal, because there's no `If` statement to go with it.

If you want an `Else` statement on a separate line of code, then you need to switch to *block syntax* - which means the `Then` keyword is where the `If` statement ends:

```
  If .Range("C" & i).Value = "No Approval Required" Then 
       .Range("F" & i).Value = ""
  Else
      '....
  End If
```

Answer (score 3):

### Explination

---

You can use the `IF` statement in one of two syntax structures:

> One Line:
>
> `If [this] Then [That]`

> Multi Line:
>
> ```
> If [This] Then
>     [That]
> End If
> ```

The multi-line allows you to check for multiple `If` statements or use the `ElseIf`. Note that this can not be done in the one liner version:

> ```
> If [This(1)] Then
>     [That1] 
>   ElseIf [This(2)] Then
>     [That2] 
>   ElseIf
>     [That3]
> End If
> ```

---

### Implementing

---

You can turn your `IF` statement into a one liner like this:

```
For i = 1 To 3000
    With Sheets("Order Approvers")
      If .Range("C" & i).Value = "No Approval Required" Then .Range("F" & i).Value = ""
    End With
Next i
```

Or you can use the block version like this:

```
For i = 1 To 3000
    With Sheets("Order Approvers")
      If .Range("C" & i).Value = "No Approval Required" Then 
        .Range("F" & i).Value = ""
      End If
    End With
Next i
```

Or you can update to use the `Else` statement

```
For i = 1 To 3000
    With Sheets("Order Approvers")
        If .Range("C" & i).Value = "No Approval Required" Then 
          .Range("F" & i).Value = ""
        ElseIf [What?] Then
            'Do what?
        End If
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: How do I get an else if in it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to close your `If` statement with an `End If`.

Comment: I am trying this but it gives me Else without if error  For i = 1 To 3000
    With Sheets("Order Approvers")
    If .Range("C" & i).Value = "No Approval Required" Then _
        .Range("F" & i).Value = ""
    End With
    Next i
    
    For i = 1 To 3000
    With Sheets("Order Approvers")
    If .Range("C" & i).Value = "Spend (1 or 2 or 3)" Then _
        .Range("F" & i).Value = ""
    End If
    ElseIf .Range("C" & i).Value = "Spend First Approver Mandatory (1 then 2 or 3" Then _
        .Range("F" & i).Value = ""
    End If
    End With
    Next i

Comment: The one in the original question works fine but I need to check more conditions

Comment: Don't drop code like this in a comment. This should be in the _question_ as part of your research which you can easily add with an [edit].